# Correct way to filter results with if statement in bash loop

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

I'm trying to work out a loop that will let me ignore some matches. So far I have:

```
for d in /home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js/lib/*.js ;  do
    if [[ $d =~ /*.min.js/ ]];
    then
        echo "ignore $d"
    else
        filename="${d##*/}"
        echo "$d"
        #echo "$filename"
    fi

done
```

However when I run it, they still seem to get included. What am I doing wrong?

```
/home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js/lib/underscore.js.min.js
/home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js/lib/tiny-slider.js
/home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js/lib/tiny-slider.js.min.js
/home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js/lib/underscore.js
```

BTW I'm a bit of a newbie with bash, so please be kind ;)

Comment: Remove `/`s and replace `=~` with `==`, use `if [[ $d == *.min.js ]]`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/eM7ncJ)

Comment: Ah you star! I knew I must be missing something. I'm coming from Perl so quite different in the way it works with matching :) Please add that as an answer and I will accept when it lets me

Comment: Remove them at the begining `for file in *[!min].js; { echo $file; }`

Comment: @Ivan thanks - but I needed to also do a few more conditional regexes - so easier to do after :) (I also want to report that its excluding those files, so they need to be in the original list)

Answer (score 5):

In Bash, regular expressions are not enclosed in `/`, so you should change your test to:

```
if [[ $d =~ \.min\.js$ ]]
```

As well as removing the enclosing `/`, I have escaped the `.` (otherwise they would match any character) and added a `$` to match the end of the string.

But in fact you can use a simpler (and marginally faster) glob match in this case:

```
if [[ $d = *.min.js ]]
```

This matches any string that ends in `.min.js`.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? This is the right answer.